# JS to unhide elements of in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi I really very naive and I am  learning JS to manipulate DOM but I have been failing all the while

below I have given a HTML content similar div are present in one page. I need to unhide the content where the Type= "hidden" this should happen for all similar input id in the page.

Secondly I need to hyperlink the value="XXXXX" in google search how Do I create a hyperlink for that using JS. Thanks a lot I totally naive into this.
and how do I run it in specific websites using user script manager.

```
< input id="binCounts&#39;4&#39;.binItemsAttributesList&#39;0&#39;.asin" 
  name="binCounts[&#39;4&#39;].binItemsAttributesList[&#39;0&#39;].asin"    
  type="hidden" value="XXXXXX"/ >
```

Comment: Your input id looks very complicated

Comment: Hi, I suggest you to edit your question, because currently it sounds like you demand a working code, which is not really appreciated on this page

Answer (score 2):

Type= "hidden" is an input type, not a visibility option, so you can't just unhide it. You have to change the field type to "text". This can be done sort of like:

```
var ifields=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < ifields.length; i++) {
                iType=ifields[i].getAttribute('type');
                if (iType==='hidden') {  
                   ifields[i].type='text;
                }
        }
```